# Docker: RUN `npm run build` gives cannot find package.json file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So the situation is that I have coupled a bash script with docker. I use bash script to pull my code from the remote repo, and then execute the `docker-compose`

Here's my dockerfile

```
FROM node:6
WORKDIR /home/ayush/project-folder
RUN pwd
RUN npm run build
CMD ["forever", "server/app.js"]
```

Here's the section of my `docker-compose.yml` that has the above service listed:

```
  web:
    build: ./client
    environment:
      - NODE_VERSION=$NODE_WEB_VERSION
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
  api:
```

And here's my simple bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
frontend=$1
backend=$2
git clone //remote_url --branch $frontend --single-branch
mv project-folder ~/
docker-compose up
```

But the issue is that the `RUN npm run build gives error`,

```
enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ayush/project-folder/package.json'
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: You have to copy the package.json onto the image

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to copy your project during build time, with

```
...
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
...
```

This will copy the whole build context (the contents of `./client`) to the working directory, which you've set to `/home/ayush/project-folder` in the previous statement.